# Enlarged Spleen

Tags: gastroenterology, symptoms, inflammation, spleen

Since I have been detected with an enlarged spleen I have wanted to know:
What are the discomforts caused by an enlarged spleen? Are there any symptoms to identify such a case?

Comment: @CareyGregory I can see that comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Mayo Clinic, the symptoms of an enlarged spleen include:

http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/enlarged-spleen/basics/symptoms/con-20029324

> An enlarged spleen may cause:
>
> ```
> No symptoms in some cases
> Pain or fullness in the left upper abdomen that may spread to the left shoulder
> Feeling full without eating or after eating only a small amount — this can occur when an enlarged spleen presses on your stomach
> Anemia
> Fatigue
> Frequent infections
> Easy bleeding
> ```

Like many illnesses, the symptoms of an enlarged spleen are non-specific and shared with many other illnesses, so there is no single symptom or set of symptoms that identifies it. Diagnosis would require examination by a physician.

Answer (score -1):

[Enlarged spleen](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/enlarged-spleen-splenomegaly-causes-symptoms-spleen-pain-and-treatment/) can reduce the number of healthy red blood cells, platelets and white cells in your bloodstream, leading to more frequent infections. Anemia and increased bleeding also are possible.
A ruptured spleen can cause life-threatening bleeding into your abdominal cavity.